# get url of items in sharepoint document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint

i have a document library in sharepoint

what is the field called for the url of the uploaded documents?
see commented line below to see what i am trying to do

```
SPDataSource dataSource = new SPDataSource();
dataSource.List = site.RootWeb.Lists["myList"];

 this.myDropDownList.DataSource = dataSource;
 this.myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
 //this.myDropDownList.DataValueField = "URL";// what should this be??
 this.myDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that you will not be able get the URL directly. FileLeafRef doent have the value full url.  One Option  I will suggest is to create a Calculated Column and generate the URL in that.

Answer (score 2):

An SPListItem has the FileRef and FileLeafRef Fields (depending on whether they are a "regular item" (FileRef) or a "document item" (FileLeafRef), they are not server relative url's though.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not quite sure about this (as I´m not that familiar with SPDataource) but my initial guess would be *FileLeafRef*.

Answer (score 0):

encoded absolute url

is the name of the field.  I would highly recommend a using a tool to expose the schema of a list or at the very least write a little code to dump the fieldnames and values.